# Editing custom label in UITableViewCell (swift 3 xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I'm trying to work out how to edit a label that I've added to a subview within my UITableView cell. Here is the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)


    var cellTitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 45,y: 2,width: 100,height: 20))
    cellTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    cellTitleLabel.text = "Title"
    cellTitleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Swiss721BT-Roman", size: 16)
    cell.addSubview(cellTitleLabel)

    return cell
}
```

now I want to be able to change the string from "title" to whatever, but  it seems that the only way i can update that text is if i remove the subview and then add a new one with updated parameters. is it not possible to do something like this:

```
cell.cellTitleLabel.text = "New Title"
```

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not create a custom subclass `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 0):

The  `cellForRowAt indexPath:` function is called every time a `tableView.reloadData()` is called.

Try setting your label text to a variable and refreshing the table.
So...

```
cellTitleLabel.text = "Title"
```

to

```
cellTitleLabel.text = myVar
```

Then update `myVar` and reload the `tableView` data.

If it is a significantly large table you can save resources by refreshing only that row or section.

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you're creating a `UILabel` as a subview of the cell when you load the cell, but you aren't retaining any reference to that label. So the cell doesn't have any property named `cellTitleLabel` anymore after it's been initialized.

I would suggest creating a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, something like this:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var cellTitleLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization Code

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func setCellContent(text: String) {

        let cellTitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 45,y: 2,width: 100,height: 20))
        cellTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        cellTitleLabel.text = text
        cellTitleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Swiss721BT-Roman", size: 16)
        self.addSubview(cellTitleLabel)

        self.cellTitleLabel = cellTitleLabel

    }


}
```

Then when you setup you call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can instantiate the custom cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.setCellContent(text: "Cell Title")

    return cell
}
```

Then you'd have a table full of `CustomTableViewCell` subclasses as it's cells, and each cell has a `UILabel` property named `cellTitleLabel` which you can change as necessary.

**EDIT:** - I forgot to add the part where you register the cell with the reuse identifier.  When you create your tableView make sure to add this:

```
tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
```

Comment: I forgot to add one thing to this, when you create your tableView you need to register the cell reuse identifier `tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")` I'll update answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is, that your solution is wrong on multiple levels. Solution of [Pierce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41623928/3067125), while being better decomposed, is wrong as well.

You see, the problem is, that you add new subview each time you dequeue the cell, but you never remove the subview from the hierarchy. What this means is that you have multiple subviews stacking one on top of another one.

Secondly, you should definitely use autolayouts, as your cell wouldn't look good on different devices.

Thirdly, using forcecasts is a short way to failures, when you start changing something. Avoid them at all costs, using pure optional instead.

The last, but not the least, I recommend using Interface Builder for creating the view layout and hierarchy.

As for the solution, your solution would fare much better, if you created a cell subclass of the following form:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var titleLabel: UILabel? {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.map { self.addSubview($0) }
            oldValue?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 45,y: 2,width: 100,height: 20))
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Swiss721BT-Roman", size: 16)

        self.titleLabel = label

    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if let cell = cell as? CustomTableViewCell {
            cell.titleLabel?.text = "Title"
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

However, to improve it even more I would recommend using something, like [IDPCastable cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=idpcastable)

It would allow you to simplify matching without force casts:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    return match(cell) { (c: CustomTableViewCell) in
        c.titleLabel?.text = "Title"
    }
}
```

And, let me stress once again, interface builder is the way to go and autolayouts are an absolute must.

Answer (score 0):

1) your problem is that you always add new `UILabel` to the cell on each call. you can see this in the 3D Debug view that more and more UILabel are stacked

2) you should create subviews and labels only once in the init of the cell

3) i have more then one type of cell displayed in a table. i created a `protocol` to decouple the internal implementation of a cell from the calling tableViewController. now you are free to create different cells and each cell is responsible for the right layout and update of content:

```
protocol UpdateableTableViewCell {
    func configCell(with data:MyTableDataModel)
}
```

now all my different cells implement this protocol:

```
class MyTinyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UpdateableTableViewCell {

    let cellTitleLabel = UILabel()

    //[...]

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        cellTitleLabel.frame = : CGRect(x: 45,y: 2,width: 100,height: 20))
        cellTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        cellTitleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Swiss721BT-Roman", size: 16)
        self.contenView.addSubview(cellTitleLabel)
    }

    // implement protocol UpdateableTableViewCell
    func configCell(with data:MyTableDataModel){
        resetCell()
        cellTitleLabel.text = data.description
    }

    ///[...]

    func resetCell(){
         // reset here all other cell ui elements to default values
    }
}
```

now i can reuse different cells with one step:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellData:MyTableDataModel = myDataArray(indexPath.row)

    // calculate the celltype depending on the current data in the cell
    let cellTypeIdentifier = getCellTypeIdentifier(cellData) 

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellTypeIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UpdateableTableViewCell {
        cell.configCell(with: cellData)
    }
}
```

and don't forget to register all your cells at the tableView:

```
tableView.register(MyTinyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tinyCell")
tableView.register(MyBigTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "bigCell")
tableView.register(MyImageTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "imageCell")
```

4) to make it more flexible you can abstract also the data model als an protocol so that you can use different models for your cells.

```
protocol MyTableDataModel {
    let description:String { get }
    let title:String { get }
    let imageUrl:String { get }    
}
```